# How to update all npm packages in a medium/advanced project?

Tags: npm, angular-cli, package.json

I'm trying to update Angular from version 11 to 12 and I'm following this tutorial: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-12.0

When I launch this command `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12` on the terminal I have this message:

```
✔ Package successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 0 dependencies.
Package '@angular/core' is not a dependency.
```

I can't resolve in noway, nothing change in my package.json. I'm tryng to update with `npm i @angular/core@12 npi i @angular/cli@12`, it works but when I'm going to install all packages in my package.json I have a lot of problem with dependency like this:

```
            npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
            npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
            npm ERR! 
            npm ERR! While resolving: poc-architecture-angular@0.0.0
            npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@12.1.5
            npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
            npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~12.1.4" from the root project
            npm ERR! 
            npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
            npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=11.0.0 <12.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@6.1.0
            npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
            npm ERR!   @ng-select/ng-select@"^6.1.0" from the root project
            npm ERR! 
            npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
            npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
            npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
            npm ERR! 
            npm ERR! See /home/andrea/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

            npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
            npm ERR!     /home/andrea/.npm/_logs/2021-09-06T13_14_09_645Z-debug.log
```

I would to update Angular and after that all the outdated packages but I can't. Is something wrong? I tried also with `npx npm-check-updates -u` but with same dependencies issues.

This is my package.json:

```json
    {
      "name": "poc-architecture-angular",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0  --port 4200",
        "build": "NODE_ENV=production ng build --prod",
        "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=production ng build --source-map=true --prod",
        "build:local": "ng build --watch --output-path /usr/share/nginx/html && tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz dist/prod/*",
        "test": "ng test",
        "test:coverage": "ng test --no-watch --code-coverage --browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "stylelint": "stylelint --fix \"src/**/*.scss\" --config .stylelintrc.json",
        "stylelint:diff": "stylelint \"src/**/*scss\" --config .stylelintrc.json",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/app/**/*.{ts,html,scss}\"",
        "format:diff": "prettier --list-different \"src/app/**/*.{ts,html,scss}\"",
        "analize": "ng build --prod --stats-json && node_modules/.bin/webpack --json | webpack-bundle-analyzer ./dist/poc-architecture-angular/stats.json",
        "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p ./tsconfig.base.json -w -s --language=it-IT -r 8081",
        "docs:json": "compodoc -p ./tsconfig.json -e json -d .",
        "storybook": "npm run docs:json && start-storybook -p 9001 --quiet -c .storybook",
        "build-storybook": "npm run docs:json && build-storybook",
        "cypress:open-local": "cypress open --config baseUrl=http://localhost:4200",
        "cypress:run-local": "cypress run --config baseUrl=http://localhost:4200",
        "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
      },
      "husky": {
        "hooks": {
          "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
      },
      "lint-staged": {
        "src/app/**/*.{ts,html,scss}": [
          "prettier --write"
        ]
      },
      "exports": {
        "./": "./*"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~12.1.4",
        "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.12",
        "@angular/common": "~12.1.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.4",
        "@angular/core": "^12.1.5",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.1.4",
        "@angular/material": "^11.2.12",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.4",
        "@angular/router": "~12.1.4",
        "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.5.0",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.5.1",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.5.0",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.5.0",
        "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.1",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "^11.1.1",
        "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.1",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.1.1",
        "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "filesize": "^6.1.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "i": "^0.3.6",
        "lodash-es": "^4.17.20",
        "luxon": "^1.26.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "ng2-date-picker": "^11.0.0",
        "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
        "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^11.0.0",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
        "ngx-webstorage": "^7.0.1",
        "npm": "^7.22.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.2",
        "@angular/cli": "^12.2.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.1.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
        "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
        "@ngrx/schematics": "^11.1.1",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.21",
        "@storybook/addon-backgrounds": "^6.1.21",
        "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.1.21",
        "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.1.21",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.21",
        "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.1.21",
        "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^6.1.21",
        "@storybook/angular": "^6.1.21",
        "@types/faker": "^5.1.7",
        "@types/fs-extra": "^5.0.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
        "@types/luxon": "^1.26.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.12.54",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
        "cypress": "^7.6.0",
        "faker": "^5.1.0",
        "husky": "^4.3.8",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.4",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
        "ng-packagr": "^12.2.1",
        "postcss": "^8.1.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "puppeteer": "~8.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
        "sonarqube-scanner": "2.8.0",
        "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
        "stylelint": "^13.6.1",
        "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^7.0.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
        "stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
        "stylelint-scss": "^3.18.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.2.6",
        "tailwindcss-multi-column": "^1.0.2",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
        "typescript": "~4.3.5",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the root directory of your project and ensure it contains a `package.json` file:

```
cd /path/to/project
```

In your project root directory, run the update command:

```
npm update
```

To test the update, run the outdated command. There should not be any output.

```
npm outdated
```

Update globally-installed packages. If you are using `npm` version 2.6.0 or earlier, run this command to update all outdated global packages:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

However, please consider upgrading to the latest version of npm.

Comment: I tried...it gives an error with dependency.   

@angular/common@"~12.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=11.0.0 <12.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@6.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select